# Extracting text using regex inside the inner parenthesis

Tags: javascript, regex

I need to extract starting from `(((Abbott ........upto...... RAPIDPOINT)))`. I tried with `\(.*\)` but this will extract all inside the brackets.

> Dialog. (See documents in available formats) (e.g., Citation/Abstract, Full text, etc.). Export documents to PDF, RTF, XML, etc.
>       10 new documents found for (ti,ab(((Abbott near/10 (assay* OR test* OR analy* OR *array*)) OR (Abbott p/1 Point P/1 Care) OR ARCHITECT OR (CELL p/0 DYN)) OR ((Alere near/10 (assay* OR test* OR analy* OR *array*)) OR (Alere NEAR/5 (Triage P/1 System)) OR INRatio OR Afinion) OR ((Beckman* p/1 Coulter near/10 (assay* OR test* OR analy* OR *array*)) OR ((Beckman* p/0 Coulter) near/2 AU????) OR (UniCel* P/1 DxC) OR (UniCel* p/1 DxI) OR ( Beckman* near/5 Access) OR (Dialog. See documents in available formats (e.g., Citation/Abstract, Full text, etc.). Export documents to PDF, RTF, XML, etc.
>       10 new documents found for (ti,ab***(((Abbott near/10 (assay* OR test* OR analy* OR *array*)) OR (Abbott p/1 Point P/1 Care) OR ARCHITECT OR (CELL p/0 DYN)) OR ((Alere near/10 (assay* OR test* OR analy* OR *array*)) OR (Alere NEAR/5 (Triage P/1 System)) OR INRatio OR Afinion) OR ((Beckman* p/1 Coulter near/10 (assay* OR test* OR analy* OR *array*)) OR ((Beckman* p/0 Coulter) near/2 AU????) OR (UniCel* P/1 DxC) OR (UniCel* p/1 DxI) OR ( Beckman* near/5 Access) OR (Access* p/1 Systeme) OR (CytoFLEX OR (cyto p/0 flex)) OR (UniCel* p/1 DxH) OR ((Coulter* p/1 LH) OR Coulter*LH)) OR ((Ortho p/0 Clinical P/1 Diagnostics) OR VITROS OR (vitros* p/1 System*) OR (VITROS* p/1 ECiQ) OR ORTHOTM OR (orthotm p/1 VISION) OR (ORTHO p/1 AutoVue*)) OR ((Instrumentation p/0 Laboratories) OR HemosIL OR ACLTOP OR (ACL p/0 ELITE) OR (GEM* P/1 Premier) OR GEM*OPL) OR ((Radiometer near/10 (assay* OR test* OR analy* OR *array*)) OR (AQT?? p/0 FLEX) OR (ABL?? p/0 FLEX) OR HemoCue*) OR ((Nova p/0 Biomedical) OR StatStrip OR (STAT p/0 PROFILE*) OR ((Nova p/0 Biomedical) near/1 Prime) OR STATPROFILE*) OR (((Siemens p/0 Healthcare) near/10 (assay* OR test* OR analy* OR *array*)) OR (ADVIA p/0 Centaur) OR (Dimension p/0 Vista) OR RAPIDPOINT))) and (ud(>20170101)) (see attachment)
>       All ProQuest Dialog alert emails are sent from: alert@proquest.com. Tip: use this email address to set up a filter and direct ProQuest Dialog alert mail to a folder other than your inbox.  OR ((Instrumentation p/0 Laboratories) OR HemosIL OR ACLTOP OR (ACL p/0 ELITE) OR (GEM* P/1 Premier) OR GEM*OPL) OR ((Radiometer near/10 (assay* OR test* OR analy* OR *array*)) OR (AQT?? p/0 FLEX) OR (ABL?? p/0 FLEX) OR HemoCue*) OR ((Nova p/0 Biomedical) OR StatStrip OR (STAT p/0 PROFILE*) OR ((Nova p/0 Biomedical) near/1 Prime) OR STATPROFILE*) OR (((Siemens p/0 Healthcare) near/10 (assay* OR test* OR analy* OR *array*)) OR (ADVIA p/0 Centaur) OR (Dimension p/0 Vista) OR RAPIDPOINT))) and (ud(>20170101)) (see attachment)
>       All ProQuest Dialog alert emails are sent from: alert@proquest.com. Tip: use this email address to set up a filter and direct ProQuest Dialog alert mail to a folder other than your inbox.

Comment: My goodness... [Markdown help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help)

Comment: I corrected the question. I am not able to mark bold

Comment: But there's a WYSIWYG editor, and I linked to the markdown help page.

Comment: I am in Mobile and finding difficulty.

Comment: You question is kinda unclear... what I understand from *Abbott ........upto...... RAPIDPOINT* is that you want `Abbott.*?RAPIDPOINT`

Comment: Mmh, there is no bold text here ...

Comment: `text.match( /\({3}(.*?)\){3}/g )` or `text.match( /\({3}(.*)\){3}/g )` are as close as you can get without actually counting parentheses to ensure you're properly matched.  These return different results.

Answer (score 0):

`(\(\(\(Abbott.*RAPIDPOINT\)\)\))` will extract from the the first instance of (((Abbott to the last instance of RAPIDPOINT))).

`(`...`)` marks the extract group. This is unneeded if you are planning to use the whole match text.
`\(\(\(Abbott` finds the start point.
`.*RAPIDPOINT\)\)\)` continues until the last instance of your end point.
`.*?RAPIDPOINT\)\)\)` would continue until the first instance of your end point.